# Shuffle a table without more than two elements of the same category one after the other

Tags: java, sorting, shuffle

I'm building an app where the user is asked to identify emotions. The emotions appear as images. There are 6 categories, with 10 images in each (joy, sadness, surprise, etc.). The presentation of the images has two conditions:

- It has to be random
- No more than two images of the same category should appear one after the other.

I've put the 60 images in a table, but of course when I shuffle it, I've got a problem with the second condition.

I'm thinking of having more tables to manually respect in the code the second condition, but it seems very inelegant (six tables that are shuffled and read one after the other).

Does anyone have a better idea?

**EDIT**

Thanks all for your answers. To be more precise, I was wondering if there's some kind of mathematics formula to do it directly.

Comment: Show us your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to build the result as a series of blocks containing one element from each category, in random order on a block-by-block basis, and with each specific image being chosen randomly from among those remaining unassigned in the category.  In that case, two items from the same category can appear consecutively only where two blocks abut.

For example, the first block might consist of images from categories (2, 3, 0, 5, 4, 1), the second from categories (5, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4), the third from categories (4, 5, 0, 3, 1, 2), etc.

This approach is not as simple as merely shuffling a single array, but you already know that you cannot satisfy your requirements with such a simple approach.

This approach also does not generate all possible image sequences meeting your criteria, but those sequences it does generate are all equally probable.

It does have the advantage that both criteria are automatically satisfied by the algorithm -- you do not have to test the result at any point to verify that, nor to modify any partial or prospective whole result before accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Each "Category" should be represented by a "table". That way you can easily shuffle each "table" and pull the first two out of it to satisfy your two conditions. You're right that this isn't very elegant but it depends on your use case and future changes.

You could create an object oriented design to represent your structure here where images would have member field "category". That way you'd have a single images table, could shuffle it and start at the beginning pulling out the correct number of category by checking each images "category" member field.

Do you have any code or more descriptions of what you're thinking of pursuing?

Comment: This approach potentially has problems with the OP's first criterion.  Although the overall sequence would indeed be random, it's not clear that all allowable sequences can be generated this way, nor that all of them have equal probability.  Whether that matters depends on precisely what the OP means by "random".

Comment: I guess that's more of a sorting problem he'll need to address.  I took this question purely as a software design question, but understood regardless.

Comment: I agree that it's a sorting problem. I've done something near from your solution for another task of the app, but there was just two categories, not six. Hence my wondering about a possible random formula to do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

A rather complex algorythm but allowing a maximum random.

- first shuffle the 6 categories of 10 images
- for first image choose randomly 1 from the 10 categories and pop last image
- for following passes:

  - choose randomly 1 from the available categories, ignoring the last category choosen and possibly empty categorie - beware special case for end see below
  - pop last image from this category

Special case for end: as we choose randomly, we can end with one single category containing images in that case (after putting one in last position), make a list of all possible insertion points (not before or after an image of same category) and insert the popped image there. Iterate until all images have been inserted

It looks complex, but each step is reasonably simple and can easily be tested. One last integration test and you can be confident in the code. It is not specialy optimized but for only 60 images it should be acceptable if it is not heavily used